# How to ensure that Strings are in UTF-8?

Tags: java, scala, utf-8, character-encoding

How to convert this String `the surveyÂ’s rules` to `UTF-8` in Scala?

I tried these roads but does not work:

```
scala> val text = "the surveyÂ’s rules"
text: String = the surveyÂ’s rules

scala> scala.io.Source.fromBytes(text.getBytes(), "UTF-8").mkString
res17: String = the surveyÂ’s rules

scala> new String(text.getBytes(),"UTF8")
res21: String = the surveyÂ’s rules
```

Ok, i'm resolved in this way. Not a converting but a simple reading

```
implicit val codec = Codec("US-ASCII").onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE).onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE)

val src = Source.fromFile(new File (folderDestination + name + ".csv"))
val src2 = Source.fromFile(new File (folderDestination + name + ".csv"))

val reader = CSVReader.open(src.reader())
```

Comment: Seems like everything works as expected, isn't it?

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg, it seems that he is lucky, and his platform default encoding is UTF-8. But this is not so in general.

Comment: The question makes no sense. A character encoding is used to convert characters to bytes and vice versa. You cannot "convert a string to UTF-8".

Answer (score 12):

Note that when you call `text.getBytes()` without arguments, you're in fact getting an array of bytes representing the string in your platform's *default encoding*. On Windows, for example, it could be some single-byte encoding; on Linux it can be UTF-8 already.

To be correct you need to specify exact encoding in `getBytes()` method call. For Java 7 and later do this:

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

val bytes = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

For Java 6 do this:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset

val bytes = text.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
```

Then `bytes` will contain UTF-8-encoded text.

Answer (score 5):

Just set the JVM's `file.encoding` parameter to `UTF-8` as follows:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

It makes sure that `UTF-8` is the default encoding.

Using `scala` it could be `scala -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`.